# Eclipse e4 RCP - Integration from Xtext Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, xtext

I'm new to RCP development and stumbling around one problem. I created an e4 example Application with an Application.e4xmi. I now want to use some external editor. I got the sources from a github repo (https://github.com/franca/franca). This repo contains some xtext generated Editors which I want to integrate into my new e4 Application. Now I'm not really sure if I should use the feature, only the DSL parts or also the UI parts as plugins and what's the best way of integrating the editors. I also recognized that there seem to be some compatibility issues with the e3 and the e4 parts but I can't really find a proper solution to work around.

I already imported serveral plugins from this repo into my workspace and tried to link them to my e4 application. I also tried the import plugin from jar which didn't work any better. It also won't work with the Feature. 
I'm sorry for this question but within 2 days of looking around the internet I couldn't find a solution how to setup my project right. Although I found some indicators for the compatibility problems like the shared element id org.eclipse.ui.editorss I didn't really understand what to do neither did it work like shown in these tutorials. Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't use XText but it is almost certainly 3.x compatibilty mode plugins - which means it won't work in a pure e4 environment. You would need to do a 3.x style RCP or some sort of hybrid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thats kind of what I thought. So I have to possible ways. A classic 3.x RCP or an hybrid using the compatibility layer. Do you know some good tutorial how to set up a project as a hybrid or maybe a good example on github?

Comment: I haven't investigated hybrids.